# Dot products, cross product, and the (1,2) tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

How is the cross product a (1,2) tensor? If you do not mind, explain the question in terms of multilinear functions.  Wiki's answer confused me.

Answer (score 2):

If $V$ is a vector space, a $(1,2)$ tensor is a trilinear map $T:V^*\times V \times V \to \Bbb R$. It may be naturally identified with a map $\widetilde{T}:V\times V\to V$ via the relation $$T(\alpha,v,w) = \alpha(\widetilde{T}(v,w)).$$So, $(1,2)$-tensors can be seen as $V$-valued $(0,2)$-tensors. This is precisely what the cross product is, for $V =\Bbb R^3$, a bilinear map $\times:\Bbb R^3\times \Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Thank you for your timely response.  Is tilde T bilinear in character?

Comment: Yes, that goes without saying.